# Find row with minimum positive numbers in a 2D array

Tags: c#

I have a n * n array which has each row sorted from left to right in ascending order. Array holds integer values. I want to find the row with fewest number of positive numbers and if there are multiple rows with same number of positive numbers, I would prefer to return the row with least index. NOTE : I want my program to run in O(n) time complexity and not )(n^2). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: looking forward to seeing some code so I can help you.

Comment: I can only think of an O(nlogn) solution - binary search each row for the first positive number, say you find it at index `i` -> there is `n-i` positive numbers on this row. Repeat for n rows.

Comment: An improvement to that solution will be to start each row only from greater `i` you have found so far so in the best case it will get O(n)

Comment: @jurl is right. your best chance is to get O(nlogn). In addition to that solution, you can check each next row from the first positive value position of the current minimum row that will save some computation as well and your best case will become O(n) if the first row is the one you need and worst case will be  O(nlogn) if the last row is the one you need and all prevous rows have all negative values.

Comment: Each row is sorted left to right, but are the rows arranged in any particular order in the matrix?

Comment: Some special cases: If any value in the last column is negative, you're done (no other row can have fewer positive numbers). If the first column is entirely positive, you're done (no row can have any negative numbers).

Comment: @BurnsBA The numbers on each row does not have any relationship with the numbers on other rows. Elements in a given row are sorted in ascending order from left to right.